# counting number of mutated rows dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

How do I count the number of mutated rows in dplyr?

Let say I'm doing a mutate operation on a column and conditionally changed the values in certain rows. In particular I used `mutate(df,columnn = str_replace_all(column, "a", "A")` from the stringr package to conditionally mutate some rows in a tibble.

Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
diamonds %>%
  mutate(cut = str_replace_all(cut, "a", "A"))
```

How could I extract the count/number of rows that have been mutated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare the mutated rows with the originals.  For example, add the following to the end of your chain and you'll get the number of altered rows:

```
... %>% { sum(.$cut != diamonds$cut) }
# [1] 23161
```

The full code would be

```
diamonds %>%
    mutate(cut = str_replace_all(cut, "a", "A")) %>%
    { sum(.$cut != diamonds$cut) }
# [1] 23161
```

Comment: thanks! what does the {} operator do within the context of a dplyr chain? Never seen it before

Comment: @AjjitNarayanan - It allows `sum(.$cut != diamonds$cut)` to be evaluated without error.  It otherwise won't evaluate.